# Why doesn't MDN have a <meta name="keywords"> tag for their seo?

Tags: html, seo

So I'm starting to learn about SEO and thought I would inspect some of the websites. I saw that W3schools has this tag for keywords:

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

```
<meta name="Keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript,SQL,PHP,jQuery,XML,DOM,Bootstrap,Web development,W3C,tutorials,programming,training,learning,quiz,primer,lessons,references,examples,source code,colors,demos,tips">
```

and I googled "Image element" just to see how MDN ranks expecting them to have keywords using "Image element" but couldn't find any meta tag with the keywords attribute using my browser dev tools.

Page I inspected: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

So what technique does MDN use for keywords? Is there an advantage to it over using the `<meta name="keywords">` tag?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO advice. It might be on-topc on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 3):

Because:

1. this tag is not mandatory
2. it has been abused way too often (not trustable)
3. real content displayed to user is more trustworthy (that's where search engines look for keywords)